# View with drawable transparent background without using parent's color

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

**Context:**

I have a constraint layout with a background color with a rectangle inside which has a transparent background.

I would like the background of the rectangle to not inherit the parent's color and essentially have no color. However, transparent does not work as it shows the parent color.

See screenshot:

[image]

Constraint layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <View
      android:id="@+id/rectangleOverlay"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="306dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="65dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="65dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
      android:background="@drawable/overlay_rectangle"
      app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Rectangle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rectangle_shape">
  <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/white" />
  <padding android:left="2dp"
      android:top="2dp"
      android:right="2dp"
      android:bottom="2dp" />
  <corners android:radius="5dp" />
  <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Transparent means that it literally has no color, the common procedure is that it will "inherit" the background color of its parent view.

If you do not want that behaviour, you will have to either change your layout so the `rectangleOverlay` is not a child of your black layout or explicitly assign a color value for your `rectangleOverlay`.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a [layer-list drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#LayerList) like a kind of photo mount?

The magenta-colored bottom layer in the following picture is just meant for demonstration purposes:

[image]

If you remove the `item` containing the magenta-colored rectangle then you have a black frame and a transparent center area

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:id="@+id/remove_me"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ff00ff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape
            android:id="@+id/rectangle_frame"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="40dp"
                android:color="@color/black"/>

            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="38dp"
        android:left="38dp"
        android:right="38dp"
        android:top="38dp">
        <shape
            android:id="@+id/rectangle_shape"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#00ff00"/>
            <padding
                android:bottom="42dp"
                android:left="42dp"
                android:right="42dp"
                android:top="42dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```